# Generics help needed

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, recursion, c#-3.0, recursive-query

I don't know how to explain this, I want the following method to work but it gives me error saying

> The `as' operator cannot be used with a non-reference type parameter`
>   T'. Consider adding `class' or a reference type constraint.

Could anyone help me solve this?

```
public T GetRoot<T>() {
    if (this is T)
        return this as T;
    if (parent != null)
        return parent.GetRoot<T>();
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public T GetRoot<T>() where T:Class
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you find that problem is in a type that you are passing in.
Make that type null-able and try again

```
T?
```